# Invoicing Program Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, io, database

This is my invoicing program I made for myself to keep track of purchases people made from me. (Yes I know eBay does this for me but I wanted to see what I could make.) Basically it can search the invoice file for a keyword (the invoice number) or lets you enter a new invoice to a file named usb.txt. It is usb.txt because I was selling USB cables at the time.

```
#Invoice Entering Program Ebay

print("Ebay Invoice Program\n")


while True:
    file = input("Enter 0 to Quit. Enter S to Search The File. Press ENTER to Input new Entries *Case Sensitive*: " )
    if file == "0":
        print("Exiting Program...")
        break
    elif file=="S":
        keyword = input("Enter Invoice Number to Search For: ")
        look_in = "usb.txt"
        search_file = open(look_in,"r")
        with open(look_in, "r") as search_file:
            for line in search_file:
                if keyword in line:
                    print(line)

    else:

        Name = input("Enter Buyer Name: ")
        InNum = input("Enter Ebay Invoice Number: ")
        Quant = int(input("Enter Amount Bought: "))
        Price = Quant * 5
        with open("usb.txt", "at")as out_file:
            out_file.write(
                "Name: %s || Invoice Number: %s || Quantity: %s || Price:$ %s \n\n" % (Name, InNum, Quant, Price))
            out_file.close()
            print("File edits made")
```

I'm pretty new to python and programming in general. If you have any suggestions on how I could improve it or any ideas to add functionality I'd love to hear it! This was written in python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 8):

What happens if the user types "s"?  Your program says:

```
Enter Buyer Name:
```

Oops!  It was supposed to be uppercase, wasn't it?  I'm not sure why you want it to be case-sensitive, but you should tell the user of his mistake instead of just going on as if you know what he meant.  That means, I would change `else:` to `elif not file:` and add an `else:` that prints something like `Sorry, I don't know what that means.`

---

Your `search_file = ...` line is useless because you redefine `search_file` on the next line (`with open(...) as search_file:`).  By the way, I am happy to see that you are using `with` blocks.  That is rare, but good practice.

---

Your naming is not consistent with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, on [Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability...

---

You use `int(input(...))` without a `try` block.  That is dangerous.  If the user types something that is not a valid integer, there will be a very nasty error.  You should use a `while` loop that keeps going until the user types a valid integer.  The validity test would, of course, be with a `try`-`except` block.

---

`out_file.close()` is unnecessary in your `with` block.  The `with` block will take care of closing the file.

---

You might want to take a look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  With its help, you are more flexible with the format in which the entries are printed.  Your printing code might end up looking something like this:

```
template = "Name: {name} || Invoice Number: {invoice} || Quantity: {quantity} || Price: ${price}\n\n"

...

with open(look_in, "rt") as search_file:
    for line in csv.DictReader(search_file):
        if line['invoice'] == keyword:
            print(template.format(**line))
```

Your writing code:

```
with open("usb.txt", "at") as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, (
      'name', 'invoice', 'quantity', 'price')):

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({
        'name': Name, 'invoice': InNum, 'quantity': Quant,
        'price': Price})
```

As it is, an entry might be displayed just because its name includes the invoice number.  With a csv file, that is no longer possible.

Answer (score 2):

#### Constants on top

```
look_in = "usb.txt"
...
Price = Quant * 5
```

The file to look in may reasonably change in the future as may the price per unit (currently 5).

I suggest writing the constants on top in UPPERCASE to allow easier modification of the program.

#### Useless `.close()`

`with` closes the file automatically so you can remove the `close` at the end of your code.

#### Functionality modularization

Finding the lines where a string is present given a text is one unit of work that is independent from the rest of the logic, so I would write a function for it.